# DataTable Jquery plugin handle more than 100k record

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datatable

I had pluged in DataTables but somehow when I tried to load a database that has 100k row it had too low to load the page. If any recommendation on handle this big data in table in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [Pagination](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination) & [Server side support](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side).

Your user won't be seeing all 100k records simultaneously anyways..